# IdeaVim: How to cycle through list items without using arrow keys?

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

Is there a way to move through list of suggestions without leaving keyboard home row? I am looking for some kind of vim-style analog to up/down arrow actions.[image: list of suggestions in IntelliJ IDEA]

Comment: Its a feature request not question ) go to youtrack https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM

Comment: I would disagree, because I don't know, whether IdeaVIM has such functionality at all. The answer I expect is one of:

a) "No, there's no such feature" + optional workaround;

b) "Yes, there is such feature, and here is how to do it".

Answer (score 5):

### For people reading this on 2019

you can use `Ctrl` + `n` and `Ctrl`+ `p` to cycle the autocomplete options

Reference: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-438#comment=27-520874

Answer (score 4):

You can bind <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> to arrow keys globally in your OS. No more leaving the home row, ever! <kbd>Fn</kbd> is often located in the bottom left corner of the keyboard where you can easily reach it with your left palm.

On OS X you can remap the keys using excellent [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) software (formerly known as KeyRemap4MacBook) which has a "Vi mode" preset.

On Linux there are several solutions using xmodmap or XKB, see https://superuser.com/questions/96299/mapping-superhjkl-to-arrow-keys-under-x. You might need to substitute Fn for <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>: I'm not sure if <kbd>Fn</kbd> is visible to key remapping code at all.

Not sure if there are any options on Windows.

Also, certain high-end keyboards can remap keys in hardware as well.

Comment: These are some very interesting ideas and resources, thank you for sharing! Inspired by these, I will consider the idea of remapping LCtrl to CapsLock, and make LCtrl that magic key that would turn h,j,k,l to arrow keys.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, you can use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) to remap <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> to <kbd>Down</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd>

```
#j::Send {Down}
#k::Send {Up}
```

Answer (score 1):

On OS X one can use <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. No external tools required!

Answer (score 0):

"Up" and "Down" are Editor actions within idea and can be remapped without external tools or plugins.

Go to Settings > Keymap and search for "Up" or "Down" and you can add a shortcut to these actions - fear not: you can keep the old keybinding as an alternative and intellij will let you know if you create a conflict.

I have them set to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>

[image: image of the related settings-dialog]